# How to get the latest drawn point coordinates in TeeChart for Javascript/HTML5?

Tags: javascript, teechart

I need to know the latest drawn point coordinates and draw some figures there. I saw some function CalcPosValue somewhere but didn't see for a java script.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In TeeChart JavaScript the `CalcPosValue` functions are just called `Calc`.
See the demo [here](http://www.steema.com/files/public/teechart/html5/latest/demos/canvas/custom_paint.htm), and the documentation [here](http://teechart.net/docs/teechart/jscript/lib/Tee.Chart.Axis.html).

Comment: Hi ,
thanks a lot for the solution. Everything is ok. 
We need one more thing: is it possible to find the minYValue/maxYValues only for a visisble points on chart in javascript?

Comment: You should loop the values manually to search the min and max visible values in a series